# Can't find Windows Phone 8 speech recognition reference

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, reference, speech-recognition, speech

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone 8 where I need to reconize speech input. I'm trying to use this code:

```
SpeechRecognizerUI speechRecognition = new SpeechRecognizerUI();
SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await speechRecognition.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

if (recoResult.ResultStatus == SpeechRecognitionUIStatus.Succeeded)
{
  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You said {0}.", recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text));
}
```

But I need to add a reference, a reference that I can't find in the "add reference" dialog, or with the browse function. Do I need to download it somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to add a reference manually. Add

```
using Windows.Phone.Speech.Recognition;
```

to the top of your code.

Comment: There we go! Thanks! I was looking at another reference, but this is what I was looking for:)